# Can't manage two get page numbers shown at the outside of a twosided PDF

Tags: latex, lyx

I am trying to change the page numbering from being at the footer's center, to a more book like page numbering where the numbers are always located at the outside of a page (odd page nubmer -> left sided, even page number -> right sided).

I am not very familiar with Lyx, so I don't know which code parts of my Lyx file are relevant to attach here.

I tried using fancy but this didn't solve the problem. Using the code below, the page numbers are always displayed at the right lower corner.

My attempt to  fix it using fancy:

```latex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

First 85 lines of my Lyx file:

```latex
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass book
\options oneside
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
customHeadersFooters
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language ngerman
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family sfdefault
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures false
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 3cm
\topmargin 3cm
\bottommargin 3cm
\secnumdepth 5
\tocdepth 5
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style polish
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 2
\paperpagestyle fancy
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body
```

If any further code is needed, feel free to ask me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `book` class but with a `onside` layout:

```
\textclass book
\options oneside
```

You will have to change that to `twoside` (the default for `book`). I cannt tell you how to do that since I am not a LyX user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Changing it the option to "twoside" enlarged the spaces between some random paragraphs so that there where ten page more in the end.

Comment: The footer was displayed the same way as before.

Comment: @BernhardScharrer Are you referring to the start pages of a chapter or all pages? Are there any errors/warnings in the LaTeX log?